# When is the task at `create_task()` executed in asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

In the following code:

```
import asyncio

async def task_func():
    print('in task_func')
    return 'the result'


async def main(loop):
    print('creating task')
    task = loop.create_task(task_func())
    print('waiting for {!r}'.format(task))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return_value = await task
    print('task completed {!r}'.format(task))
    print('return value: {!r}'.format(return_value))


event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
try:
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main(event_loop))
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

When I execute the code, the result is the following:

```
creating task
waiting for `<Task pending coro=<task_func() running at <ipython-input-29-797f29858344>:1>>`
in task_func
task completed `<Task finished coro=<task_func() done, defined at <ipython-input-29-797f29858344>:1> result='the result'>`
return value: 'the result'
```

But I don't understand when the code you set at `loop.create_task(task_func())` is executed. Specifically, I assumed when you add a task to the event loop, it is executed soon, so I thought `in task_func` is printed before `waiting for <Task...`.

Then I found it is *always* executed after the `waiting for <Task...`, so I added `await asyncio.sleep(2)`, but only found that the `in task_func` is printed before the finish of 2 seconds.

I also added `task_func_2()` which is practically the same as `task_func()` and create its task below `task = loop.create_task(task_func())` but do NOT add `return_value_2 = await task2`, so the `await` does not execute the task (otherwise the `task_func_2()` is never executed).

So now I got confuesed. When is the task is executed after it is added to the event loop in `loop.create_task()`?

Comment: It can’t run until you await something to return control back to the event loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Specifically, I assumed when you add a task to the event loop, it is executed soon, so I thought `in task_func` is printed before `waiting for <Task....`

"Executed soon" doesn't mean executed right away. Instead, you can think of it as "executed the first chance we get," *we* being the event loop. Since `print` immediately follows the call to `create_task`, at that point the event loop hasn't yet had a chance to run at all. To give event loop a chance to run, you must return to the event loop, either by returning from the current coroutine, or by awaiting something that blocks.

When you `await` a blocking coroutine such as `asyncio.sleep()`, the coroutine will temporarily suspend itself and relinquish control to the event loop. The event loop will look at what else there is to do before the sleep elapses and will find the tasks scheduled using `create_task` in its run queue. This is why `task_func` and `task_func_2` are executed when the `main` coroutine awaits the sleep - but not before that, and regardless of whether you `await` them in particular or something else that blocks.

`await`ing a coroutine such as `task_func` means requesting its result then and there, and being prepared to wait for it if the coroutine suspends. (Waiting on something that suspended automatically defers execution to the event loop, allowing other coroutines to make progress.) Although the implementation differs, an `await` is conceptually similar to `join`ing a thread.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand it. *"executed the first chance we get,"* - Then how likely is it that the function after the `create_task()` is executed before the task? I put `for i in range(100000): print(i)` atfer the `create_task()`, but it still got executed after all the print statement are done. So I'm still confused how I can know when the task at `create_task()` is going to be executed...

Comment: @Blaszard You need to give the event loop a chance to run, which running `print()` in a `for` loop doesn't. More precisely, you need to either exit the current coroutine, or `await` something. This is what the second paragraph tries to explain.